# 翻訳の誤り: 誤記および余分な促音

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, ヘルプ

> ヘルプ センター > 信用度とモデレーション
>   投票が重要なのはなぜ?
>   https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

の項目列挙の後の段落で誤記があります。ボールドで強調表示しておきます。

> 編集者、クローザー、モデレーターのクラスが、サイトの運営と管理を支援できるのは、投票を通してのみです。投票は、サイトのリーダーシップが形成される手続きです。信用度リーグに、週、月、四半期、年、またはこれまでの信用度によって**情意のユーザー**の詳細が表示されるのはそのためです。

原文の
https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote
を確認すると、この部分は **top users** に対応しているようなので **上位のユーザー** に変更すべきです。

また、最終段落で余分な促音「っ」が含まれています。終わりから2文目です。ボールドで強調表示しておきます。

> 質問または回答に賛成票を投じることは、その投稿が興味深く、よく研究されており、有用であることをコミュニティに知らせます。反対票を投じることはその逆で、その投稿に間違った情報が含まれていること、調査が不十分であること、または情報を伝えていないことを示します。投稿に投票する人が多いほど、後で訪れる人がその投稿に含まれる情報に確信を持つ **っ** ことができます。賛成票は、時間と労力をかけて良質な投稿を書いた作成者に感謝の気持ちを表すためのとても良い方法であることは言うまでもありません。

以上２項目に関して訂正をお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

更新しました：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

> 編集者、クローザー、モデレーターのクラスが、サイトの運営と管理を支援できるのは、投票を通してのみです。投票は、サイトのリーダーシップが形成される手続きです。信用度リーグに、週、月、四半期、年、またはこれまでの信用度によって上位のユーザーの詳細が表示されるのはそのためです。

Comment: 後者（促音）の削除もお願いします。

Comment: @riocampos すみません、「後者（促音）」は何ですか？

Comment: 『投稿に投票する人が多いほど、後で訪れる人がその投稿に含まれる情報に確信を持つ **っ** ことができます。』の『っ』です。

Comment: @riocampos 完了済みです。

Comment: 閲覧したときには未訂正でしたので。ごめんなさい。ありがとうございました。